# How to fix error "System.InvalidOperationException" in a partial view

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, model, partial-views

Hello I'm trying to add a database entry form into a modal that's on a page that displays info retrieved from my database, I've created a scaffold template using visual studios and it contains all the model information in it, I then put that into a partial view to display it through the model but I keep getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo'"
```

Here is my homepage:

```
@model IEnumerable<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
<li class="one">
    <h5>Please begin creating your network structure:</h5> 
    <button id="modal-opener">Add a new building</button>
</li>
<li class="two">

</li>
</ol>

<div class="Container">

    <div class="Box1">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {<div>
            <h4 class="Heading">@item.buildingName</h4>
            <h4 class="Heading">@item.buildingNumber</h4>
            <p>@item.buildingDesc1</p>
            <p>@item.buildingDesc2</p>
            <p>@item.buildingDesc3</p>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
    ....
</div>

<div id="Modal" title="Building Details">

@Html.Partial("buildingForm")

</div>
```

Here is my Partial View:

```
@model TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>buildingInfo</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
    </div>
    ....
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller Action :

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    thDB _db = new thDB();

    public ActionResult building()
    {
        var buildingModel = _db.buildings.ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        return View(buildingModel);
    }

    public ActionResult buildingForm()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Comment: the error says all, your partial view expects ``TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo`` as Model while you are passing ``List<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>``

Comment: remove ``FirstOrDefault()`` it is not needed, it will throw expception as your view needs ``IEnumerable<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding what you want, you want to display the list in your main `View`, then you need some change in your action:

```
public ActionResult building()
{
    var buildingModel = _db.buildings.ToList();//you have to remove the FirstOrDefault() extension method

    return View(buildingModel);
}
```

And in your view, replace this line:

```
 @Html.Partial("buildingForm")
```

By this :

```
 @Html.Partial("buildingForm", new buildingInfo()) //
```

As your partial view requires an object you can pass from this line.
I hope it will help.

Comment: One thing though, The create/insert modal is popping up with everything in it but its not inserting to the database. I've simulated scaffold template that is created. I was missing one peace of code  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult buildForm(buildingInfo buildinginfo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.buildings.Add(buildinginfo);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return PartialView(buildinginfo);
        } This I presume saves the data but it doesn't work, Any clue?

Comment: In your partial view, change this line `
@using (Html.BeginForm())` to :
@using (Html.BeginForm("buildForm","Home"))`` as I guess this action above is in `HomeController`. Just one thing after saving in the database you could redirectToAction instead returning a PartialView. But have try with the first change and then try with the second change

Answer (score -1):

The error says all what's the problem.

Your partial view expects **Model** of type `TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo` while you are passing `List<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>`

which means you are returning `List<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>` but in your partial view it is :

```
@model TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo
```

replace it with:

```
@model List<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>
```

or return single object form the action.

**UPDATED:**

Replace `Html.Partial("buildingForm")` with: `@Html.RenderAction("buildingForm")`

and you action should be like this:

```
public ActionResult buildingForm() { 

var model = new buildingInfo(); 

return View(model); 

}
```

Your PartialView its name should be **buildingForm.cshtml** and it should be in **Views>>Home**:

```
@model TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>buildingInfo</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
    </div>
    ....
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Your **building** action :

```
public ActionResult building()
    {
        var buildingModel = _db.buildings.ToList();

        return View(buildingModel);
    }
```

Comment: I deleted this line from my controller:

    var buildingModel = _db.buildings.ToList();

This was the cause but now I cannot retrieve the data on my home page.

Comment: on your partial view top add ``@model List<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>``

Comment: i mean replace ``@model TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo`` with ``@model List<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>``

Comment: I put it in but now it cannot find @Html.LabelFor(model => model.buildingNumber). 
ERROR: System.Collections.Generic.List<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'buildingNumber' and no extension method 'buildingNumber'

Comment: do like this, you need to return one object instead of list..``var buildingModel = _db.buildings.ToList().FirstOrDefault();``

Comment: this will return only one object from the list

Comment: It didn't work ERROR: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo]'

Comment: which view are you returning? main view or partial view....post your action please so things are more clear

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        thDB _db = new thDB();

        public ActionResult building()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            var buildingModel = _db.buildings.ToList().FirstOrDefault();


            return View(buildingModel);
        }

        public ActionResult buildingForm()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
}

Comment: your action: ``public ActionResult buildingForm() { var model = new building(); return PartialView(model); }``

Comment: you are not passing model in the partial view.

Comment: and also instead of ``Html.Partial("buildingForm")`` use this: ``@Html.RenderAction("buildingForm")``

Comment: var model = new building(); is giving me an error.saying that I cannot use building(); as a type. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: creating an object of building entity

Comment: sorry you need to create object of ``buildingInfo``

Comment: like this: ``public ActionResult buildingForm() { var model = new buildingInfo(); return PartialView(model); }``

Comment: Hi, I see what your doing there but I rebuilt and ran it and it still gave me an error:


The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo]'

Comment: Remove FirstOrDefault from mainview action

Comment: Still giving me errors saying it can't find definition for buildingNumber etc. I changed the the ToList(); to a linq query:var buildingModel = from r in _db.buildings
                                orderby r.buildingNumber
                                select r;
However its still giving me errors. I tested both separately so they both work but not together.

Comment: I've tried the following code which I is similar to you are doing:      [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult buildingForm(buildingInfo buildinginfo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.buildings.Add(buildinginfo);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return PartialView(buildinginfo);
        }

Comment: It is post method you need to write get method as well